# Trying to setup capifony + amazonec2

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2, capistrano, ssh-keys

I'm following the [instructions](http://capifony.org/) to setup capifony. Now I'm in the step 4 to setup the production server. This is my configuration file:

```
# deploy.rb

set   :application,   "MyFirm"
set   :deploy_to,     "/var/www/myfirm.com"
set   :domain,        "dev.myfirm.com"

set   :scm,           :gitrepoit
set   :repository,    "ssh://myfirm@94.147.25.115:/home/myfirm/myfirm.git"


set :user, "ec2-user"
set :domain, "ec2-46-137-123-97.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join("foo.key")]


role  :web,           domain
role  :app,           domain
role  :db,            domain, :primary => true

set   :use_sudo,      false
set   :keep_releases, 3
```

But when I execute `cap deploy:setup`, though I've set the public key in the configuration file, it asks me for a password...

```
  * executing `deploy:setup'
  * executing "mkdir -p /var/www/myfirm.com /var/www/myfirm.com/
releases /var/www/myfirm.com/shared /var/www/myfirm.com/shared/app/
logs /var/www/myfirm.com/shared/web/uploads"
    servers: ["ec2-46-137-123-97.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
Password:
```

Any idea?

capifony 2.1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well.. I thought the path in `ssh_options[:keys]` is relative to the configuration file (deploy.rb) but actually is relative to the cap file (/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/cap).

This is working (atfer copying foo.key in /var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/):

```
ssh_options[:keys] = ["foo.pem")]
```

absolute paths work also of course:

```
ssh_options[:keys] = ["/home/me/foo.pem")]

ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["HOME"], "foo.pem")]
```

My last release:

```
# deploy.rb

set   :application,   "MyFirm"
set   :deploy_to,     "/var/www/myfirm.com"
set   :domain,        "dev.myfirm.com"

default_run_options[:pty] = true

set   :scm,           :git
set   :repository,    "myfirm@94.141.21.125:/home/myfirm/myfirm.git"

set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}

set :user, "ec2-user"
set :domain, "ec2-41-137-132-97.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
ssh_options[:keys] = ["foo.pem"]


role  :web,           domain
role  :app,           domain
role  :db,            domain, :primary => true

set   :use_sudo,      false
set   :keep_releases, 3

set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.ini"]
set :shared_children,   [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
set :update_vendors, true
```